# JMeter HTTP Authorization Manager Error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded an application in Jmeter. It shows one auto-generated 'Http Authorization Manager' where username is appearing as '${Auth_Login}' and password as ${Auth_password}. Here a pop is appearing where we are giving an OTP in the application.
Please find the below screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxIGl.jpg)

While running the script it is appearing as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C37KG.jpg)

Please help .

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a HTTP Header Manager, where you will need to set the Authorisation header. Here is all you will have to do

Create a base64 encoded value of your username and password combination

```
echo -n user123:pas123 | base64
```

The command will output an encoded value like example: **dXNlcjEyMzpwYXNzMTIz**, copy this value

In the HTTP Header Manager, create a new header, with name **Authorization** and the value **Basic**

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Shall I keep the auto generated authorization manager as it is?

Comment: You will not need it and you can safely disable it, as you are passing them in the Headers anyway. Please vote for my answer if it answers your questions. Thanks.

Comment: I am not getting any value with echo -n user123:pas123 | base64 and where I will use the encoded value? Shall I add a row in the http header manager and give Name as Authorization and Value as Basic?

Comment: You seem to have a non unix machine. You can encode it from online services. Use this link. Give the username:password string and click on encode at this site www.base64encode.org

Comment: Added a screenshot for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `KERBEROS` authentication mechanism my expectation is that you are trying to load test application which is using [Kerberos protocol](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/). I'm not sure you will be able to record and replay Kerberos-based login, you will need to specify domain/realm in the HTTP Authorisation Manager and also perform the relevant configuration in *krb5.conf* and *jaas.conf* file in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

More information:

- **Kerberos Configuration** chapter of the [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) JMeter User Manual entry
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) - a little bit more detailed information and sample configuration.